# JPanel elements are not appearing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm using the Swing library to ask a user for their zipcode, but all that is appearing is a box, without the text box, or any of the other elements that I've added in (see code). Also, you likely need to know that I'm trying to get the int AskZip() in my public static void main(String[] args) method.

```
    private static int zip;
    public static int AskZip() {
        JFrame zaWindow = new JFrame("What Zipcode");
        zaWindow.setSize(200, 300);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField("Enter Zip Here");
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Get Weather");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String sZip = tf.getText();
                int rZip = 0;
                try {
                    if (sZip.length() != 5) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid zipcode!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    } else {
                        rZip = Integer.parseInt(sZip);
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException arg) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid zipcode!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                zip = rZip;
            }
        });
        label.setText("What is your zipcode?");
        jp.add(label);
        jp.add(tf);
        jp.add(button);
        zaWindow.add(jp);
        return zip;
    }
```

Comment: `JFrame zaWindow..` Should be a modal dialog or a `JOptionPane`.  Be sure to call `pack()` on the dialog immediately before `setVisible(true)` (which should be last).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `JFrame zaWindow..`

This should be a modal dialog or a `JOptionPane`.  E.G. This country has 3 states, each with 10 postcodes.

[image: Enter Zip Code]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

class ZipQuery {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ZipNumberModel znm = new ZipNumberModel();
                JSpinner zip = new JSpinner(znm);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, zip, "Enter Zipcode", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                System.out.println("User chose " + znm.getValue());
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class ZipNumberModel extends SpinnerNumberModel {

    private ArrayList<Integer> zipCodes;
    private int index = 0;

    ZipNumberModel() {
        zipCodes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int zip = 10000;
        for (int jj = 1; jj < 4; jj++) {
            for (int ii = jj * zip; ii < jj * zip + 10; ii++) {
                zipCodes.add(new Integer(ii));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        return zipCodes.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNextValue() {
        if (index < zipCodes.size()-1) {
            index++;
        } else {
            index = 0;
        }
        return zipCodes.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPreviousValue() {
        if (index > 0) {
            index--;
        } else {
            index = zipCodes.size()-1;
        }
        return zipCodes.get(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, however, you completely changed the code... He just wants to know why it isn't appearing.

Comment: +1 for improved validation; see also [*Creating Custom Spinner Models and Editors*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#model)

Comment: @HenryHarris  *"He just wants to know why it isn't appearing."*  If he just wanted to know how to shoot himself in the foot, I would not help.  Would you?  OTOH I did address that problem in a comment over an hour ago.. *"Be sure to call `pack()` on the dialog immediately before `setVisible(true)` (which should be last)."*

Comment: @AndrewThompson There are days (that I would help ;))

Comment: @HenryHarris And when we told them, they'd want to know how to fix it. Saves time this way ;)